# Sometimes cannot select item in Listbox c#

Tags: wpf, listbox, selecteditem

In my xaml I bind a `ObservableCollection<City> Cities` to it

and the `SelectedItem` is `SelectedCity`

and sometimes when the mouse is over a item, I **cannot select** it

My ListBox looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Cities}" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedCity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="468" Margin="10,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="877">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Plz}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and in My Model the code looks like this:

```
 class CitiesModel: MyObservableCollection<City>
{
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            return _cities;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<City> _cities;


    private City _selectedCity;
    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCity;
        }
        set
        {

            _selectedCity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCity");

        }
    }
```

Can someone explain, why i sometimes cannot select an item?

Comment: Why does your viewmodel inherit from something called `MyObservableCollection<>`? Sounds suspicious... Could it be something going on in this base class that causes a rebind to the Model?

Comment: it's just a class that inherits from observablecollection and INotifyPropertyChanged and has a method calld RaisePropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

You mean once you select one, you cannot select a different one.

Your problem is that if you have in the setter.
Remove it.

```
        if(_selectedCity != value)
        {
```

City is an object.
If you compare an object to another then unless you have provided an Equals method, they will be equal if of the same type.

Hence, once you select a City then any other City is equal.

Comment: I removed the if in the setter,

However, didn't change anything.

still sometimes can't select items

Comment: Ok, I think it has something to do with the Itemssource observableCollection,

because it also happens when I remove the selectedItem